# React Emoji Picker not converting to unicode

Tags: reactjs, emoji

I'm referencing this

https://github.com/ealush/emoji-picker-react

I'm having issues rendering the actual emoji, and its not doing so. When you click on it, it should load in the emoji png, but its not.

Also looking at this

https://github.com/atatarinov/react-emoji/blob/master/app/components/ChatWindow.js

[image]

Working Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/qqmvo5924?fontsize=14

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Emoji from './components/Emoji';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import EmojiPicker from 'emoji-picker-react';
import JSEMOJI from 'emoji-js';


let jsemoji = new JSEMOJI();

// set the style to emojione (default - apple)
jsemoji.img_set = 'emojione';
// set the storage location for all emojis
jsemoji.img_sets.emojione.path = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/32/';

// some more settings...
jsemoji.supports_css = false;
jsemoji.allow_native = false;
jsemoji.replace_mode = 'unified'



const styles = theme => ({
 shadows: ["none"],
 spacing: 8,
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'left',
    width: '500px',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,

  },
  myitem:{
    margin:'40px'
  },
  emoji:{
    margin:'40px'
  }
});






class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      emoji: '',
      text:''

    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
     text: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleClick = (n, e) => {
    let emoji = jsemoji.replace_colons(`:${e.name}:`);
    this.setState({
      text: this.state.text + emoji
    });
    console.log(emoji)
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Navbar />
          <Grid container spacing={12}>
            <Grid item sm={6} className={classes.myitem}  >
              <Paper className={classes.paper} >
                <Typography variant="h2" component="h2">
                    Insert An Emoji
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                        id="standard-name"
                        label="Emoji"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        margin="normal"
                    />


                <EmojiPicker onEmojiClick={this.handleClick}/>
              </Paper>

            </Grid>

          </Grid>
          {/* insert footer here */}

          <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the emoji convertor you are using has been configured to output `img` tags. You must configure it to output unicodes instead. You need to flip the `allow_native` configuration to make that happen (yours is currently set to `false`):

```js
jsemoji.allow_native = true;
```

For more, refer the [docs](https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji#usage).